# Excel formula for finding second earliest to the earliest date in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a data query in Excel that returns multiple rows of information for a single employee. The employee are sorted by an EmployeeID, and the data contains Pay Rates and Dates.

I have sorted the information by date descending in order to give me the first Pay Rate for an employee to put within a VLookUp for another sheet in my workbook. Now I need a formula to give me to next date in line so I can find the second earliest date in the range. Can this be done?

```
Data example:
1255  7.50   06/11/2012
1255  7.00   09/11/2011
1255  6.50   05/12/2011
2548  12.50  03/02/2012
2548  12.00  01/13/2012
```

Comment: I assume that first date should be 06/11/`2011`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `VLOOKUP` use `INDEX/MATCH`!

Say your current formula is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:C,3,0)
```

This can be converted to

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

It does the same thing (search in A for a match and return the result from column C).
Now you can easily get the next match:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)+1)
```

If you want to test if it's still the same employee (in column B), the formula is a bit more complicated:

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0))=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)+1),INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)+1),"Only one entry!")
```

Comment: Thanks! for the Quick Response! That worked great but here's another question can I set that based on a criteria? Meaning If my employee has been hired and rehired several times can I say "Find the next date after this date?"

Comment: Try my suggestion - put the date in F2 and you get the next date after that for the employee in E2. Change the "column index" from 3 to 2 if you want the rate for that date rather than the date itself

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the date or the pay rate? If it's the date then if you have employee ID in E2 and first date (extracted by VLOOKUP) for that employee in F2 then this formula will give the second date

`=VLOOKUP(E2,IF(Sheet1!C$2:C$100>F2,Sheet1!A$2:C$100),3,0)`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

You can get the next date in the same way - if there isn't another date for that employee you get #N/A